# adsense won't work on certain website

Tags: adsense

I have adsense working on 2 websites; with ads I have added and inserted at two different channels - creating a channel for website 1 and website 2. I have a third website, that I have also created a designated channel and the ads will not work, at all. Within the adsense Dashboard the ads remain status of 'New' never turning to 'Active' and eventually the channel just disappears; no matter where or how I insert the ads on this website, nothing displays. It seems google has removed any option to contact adsense so am looking for a solution suggestion. Anyone have any ideas, the website is a blog setup with hopes of gathering adsense revenue; without it working there isn't much point here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdSense offers help only to customers earning above a certain limit.

Secondly, Google does not allow advertising on certain websites. I had a problem when a post on my website related to some pharmaceutical issue. Does your website contain any of the "forbidden" words?
Sites displaying Google ads may not include:

> ```
> * Violent content, racial intolerance, or advocacy against any individual, group, or organization
> * Pornography, adult, or mature content
> * Hacking/cracking content
> * Illicit drugs and drug paraphernalia
> * Excessive profanity
> * Gambling or casino-related content
> * Content regarding programs which compensate users for clicking on ads or offers, performing searches, surfing websites, or reading emails
> * Excessive, repetitive, or irrelevant keywords in the content or code of web pages
> * Deceptive or manipulative content or construction to improve your site's search engine ranking, e.g., your site's PageRank
> * Sales or promotion of weapons or ammunition (e.g., firearms, fighting knives, stun guns)
> * Sales or promotion of beer or hard alcohol
> * Sales or promotion of tobacco or tobacco-related products
> * Sales or promotion of prescription drugs
> * Sales or promotion of products that are replicas or imitations of designer goods
> * Sales or distribution of term papers or student essays
> * Any other content that is illegal, promotes illegal activity, or infringes on the legal rights of others
> ```